# git archive by adding 1 folder level

Tags: git, archive

Hi I would like to archive my git repo:

```
git archive -o rpda.zip HEAD
```

however this command creates a structure like:

```
rpda.zip
|____files_in_the_repo
```

while I would like to add a folder level like this:

```
rpda.zip
|___version_number
    |____files_in_the_repo
```

is it possible with git archive?

EDIT:

The version_number might be a variable in batch set like

```
set version_number=0.1.2
```

Comment: Where does `version_number` come from ? Latest git commit id ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
set version_number=0.1.2
git archive -o rpda.zip HEAD --prefix=%version_number%/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).